# Is vs Are; why do they use the Are instead of the Is?

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

"Vodafone are providing a useless service"

I am quite sure that the Vodafone is singular, but everyday I see even many native English speakers using the Are instead of the Is

Answer (score 1):

A company such as Vodafone can be considered to be a large group of people, therefore  *plural*, **or** a single organisation, therefore *singular*.  So you can use either:

"Vodafone are providing a useless service" is equivalent to "The employees of Vodafone are providing a useless service".

"Vodafone is providing a useless service" is equivalent to "The Vodafone  company is providing a useless service".

Comment: Max Williams. The same thought to me too

Comment: I think it's broadly a UK/US split - Brits are likely to say *my staff are useless*, Americans more inclined to *my staff is...*. Similarly, even the BBC will refer to *the Government are*, but I doubt equivalent media in the US would use the plural/collective.